# How to hit controller on saving my data of Store->Configuration in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, controllers, core-config-data

I have created some setting in Store->Configuration in Magento 2 i want to hit a controller if the setting is changed otherwise the i want the controller didn't hit.

How would i do that ?

My observer file path ( app/code/Custom/Code/Observer/ConfigObserver.php )

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Code\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var Logger
 */
protected $logger;
private $productAction;
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_pageFactory;
private $scopeConfig;
private $_objectManager;

/**
 * @param Logger $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    Logger $logger,
    Action $productAction,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $attributes = [
        'status' => 2,
        'price' => 123
    ];
    $productIds = array(10);
    $storeId = 0;
    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
}
}
```

system.xml file path ( app/code/Custom/Code/etc/adminhtml/system.xml )

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="am_general" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Rule configuration</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="am_shipping" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top am-general-admin-tab-general</class>
        <label>Rule Section</label>
        <tab>am_general</tab>
        <resource>Custom_Code::general_config</resource>
        <group id="prices" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Rule settings</label>
            <field id="add_item" translate="label" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Rule based on price</label>
                <frontend_model>Custom\Code\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field\AdditionalItem</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Custom\Code\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\AdditionalItem</backend_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

**And my event name is admin_system_config_changed_section_am_shipping.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Following event are fire after System->configuration save.**

```
admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section} -> here $section is 'general' etc.
```

Here is an example for '`admin_system_config_changed_section_general`' event. `etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_general">
        <observer name="custom_admin_system_config_changed_section_general" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and observer class is `"[Vendor][Module]\Observer\ConfigObserver"`

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getWebsite());
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getStore());
    }
}
```

You can do this same thing using plugin. `Create di.xml` "etc/di.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="admin_system_config_save_plugin" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\ConfigPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And Plugin class `'[Vendor][Module]/Plugin/ConfigPlugin.php'`

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;


class ConfigPlugin
{
    public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        // your custom logic
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Note:

'`admin_system_config_changed_section_general`' this event dispatch with 2 argument (website and store). So If you need more data like configuration fields values then you should go with 2nd solution(plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Before Applying i have one question I want to run that controller when the value is changes for that particular section else controller didn't run is it possible @Hamendra

Comment: Its possible, 'admin_system_config_changed_section_general' This can be customized & will only be called when your config have changes, its better to try it out.

Comment: okk Thanks for that will update you in some time if face any problem @Hamendra

Comment: I have followed admin_system_config_changed_section this approach and created an observer but it will always run weather i change or not change the value.
How will i check if the value is changed or not ?@Hamendra

Comment: Have you customize the event ?  admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section} -> here $section can be your section.

Comment: Yes i have added by event and check on observer file if i die on that execute it will show the value.

Comment: I mean you need to add your configuration setting's section name into observer.

Comment: Updated my observer file and event name where should i add setting's section name will you please help @Hamendra

Comment: Please add system.xml code in question.

Comment: Updated Please check.@Hamendra

Comment: admin_system_config_changed_section_am_shipping

Comment: Yes that is i figured out and added in question too.
My concern is how to hit observer file when data will be changed else not hit the observer file @Hamendra

Comment: Simply get the latest config data & old data compare it and execute it.

Comment: How would i get latest data ?
My old data i have got from database in my observer file @Hamendra

Comment: Print Observer data in observer file. You will able to see data.

Comment: I guess i'm getting my old data with $this->scopeConfig->getValue('am_shipping/prices/add_item');
But how do i print observer data will you please help @Hamendra

Comment: Get params value it should help getting new form data

Comment: By using $this->_request->getPost(); i have get the the new data and it will updated in DB also so how would i get compare the data because old value gets replaced by new value @Hamendra